# Unwanted diagram movement in GoJS Overview

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, gojs

[Overview diagrams in GoJS](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/overview.html), which consist of a rectangle representing the viewport and a smaller version of the observed diagram, show some interesting behavior:
When dragging the rectangle representing the viewport close to an edge, the whole overview diagram shifts into the opposite direction.
[image: overview diagram]

Is there any way to disable this behavior, so the diagram remains "fixed" in the upper left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug because of `diagram.autoScrollRegion` allowing the Diagram (Overview in this case which is a kind of Diagram) to scroll when you're dragging the box by an edge.

This bug will be fixed in the next release (1.5.4), but you can make a workaround by setting:

`myOverview.autoScrollRegion = 0;`